# minifyEnabled true and start./gradlew assembleRelease build failed

Tags: react-native, gradlew

When I set `minifyEnabled true` and start ./gradlew assembleRelease build failed. I tested a fresh project and existing project. Can you help me fix it?

build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle)

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true 
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

The error:

> ERROR:/Users/mesutaltas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a334453207e8f257bd8e5065fd1e9287/transformed/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.8.10.jar: R8: Type kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsResourceLoader is defined multiple times: /Users/mesutaltas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a334453207e8f257bd8e5065fd1e9287/transformed/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.8.10.jar:kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class, /Users/mesutaltas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a334453207e8f257bd8e5065fd1e9287/transformed/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.8.10.jar:META-INF/versions/9/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

`./gradlew assembleRelease`